# Excel vba userform not working if there is another excel file is opened

Tags: vba, excel

I have an userform in a.xlsm and it is working fine.

But if I open another excel workbook for example b.xlsx, my userform not working.

My userform try to find or select in b.xlsx.

how can I Restrict my userform to work in just a.xlsm even other workbooks are opened.

Comment: Please add your code, but you should reference your workbook/sheets fully, like `set wS = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("sheetname")`

Comment: @R3uK well I find this code is that suitable Application.GoTo Workbooks("mp.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("A1"), it looks working

Comment: That ain't very clear! And I'd rather use `ThisWorkbook` than `Workbooks(name)` if the code is in that specific workbook, so that even if you change its name, the code will still work! ;)

Comment: You could add code to close all other open workbooks on open of this one.  That way you won't have any other workbooks open.  And if you need to open other workbooks from within then set them to variables in order to keep track of them.

Comment: @JohnMuggins well but I need other excel file in a same time, I am checking some values